# How to include helper file from custom template?

Tags: php, class, joomla, helper

Tell me please how to include helper file from custom template?

For example i want get the the ModBreadCrumbsHelper class from /modules/mod_breadcrumbs/helper.php

in the custom template /templates/test/html/com_content/article/default.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a "core" way to add files.

```
JLoader::register('MyHelperClass', JPATH_ROOT . '/modules/mod_breadcrumbs/helper.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use include() or include_once() to achieve this.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Example: (inside /templates/test/html/com_content/article/default.php)

```
include "/modules/mod_breadcrumbs/helper.php"; // provided the directory "modules" is inside the directory containing "default.php"

$class = new ModBreadCrubmsHelper();

$class->stuff();
```

Comment: And is there any standard way, for example JDoc::Include('modue.helper.'); ?

Comment: @Vladimir - No. `jdoc:include` is used indicate where the output from other parts of Joomla or its extensions should be positioned in the overall web page. You will see things like `<jdoc:include type="component" />` in your template index.php file which indicates where to output the components and so on. To include a helper file, use the method from Jonny's answer